# Django 1.7 generic views

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I'm currently going through Django's official tutorial, and I'm having trouble trying to understand how the generic views actually work.

Source code from the official documentation:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'
```

detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

results.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

Now, I understand that `ListView` and `DetailView` are default generic views provided by Django.

How do `DetailView` and `ResultsView` generate the `question` context variable in the `detail.html` and `result.html`? Also, how is the `error_message` context variable inside the `detail.html` generated by the `DetailView` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `question` object is named after the `model` attribute of the generic view (in this case, `Question`). Detail views include such an object automatically.

If you're asking how the specific `question` object is chosen, a detail view, by default, must be passed a `pk` value from the URL, which is then used to find that object. The relevant code from polls/urls.py is as follows:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

`error_message`, on the other hand, is not included in the generic views.  It's only used in the example for the non-generic view, because that one includes it in the context explicitly:

```
return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
    'question': p,
    'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
})
```

Answer (score 1):

DetailView has a `context_object_name` parameter, which you can use to set the name of the object in the template, but if you don't set it, the `get_context_object_name` method does this:

```
def get_context_object_name(self, obj):
    """
    Get the name to use for the object.
    """
    if self.context_object_name:
        return self.context_object_name
    elif isinstance(obj, models.Model):
        return obj._meta.model_name
    else:
        return None
```

It uses the name of the model. Then `get_context_data` of the `SingleObjectMixin` puts that identifier in the context. In any case, you can also access the object with the `object` identifier.

I'm sure you can read all of this in the Django documentation, but there is [a nice page where you can explore class based views](http://ccbv.co.uk/)